# Merge text files with same prefix into one - Python

Tags: python, file, merge

I need to merge a lot of text files into a single one. All files are named "patch_***number***.txt" and they are located in different directories. I've already tried some codes but I was only able to create a file for each different "patch_***number***.txt". For example: one file for every "patch_0.txt". Here's the code:

```
import os

paths = {}
for root, directories, files in os.walk('.'):
    for f in files:
        if f.startswith('patch_', 0, 5):
            if f not in paths:
                paths[f] = []
            paths[f].append(root)

for f, paths in paths.items():
    txt = []
    for p in paths:
        with open(os.path.join(p, f)) as f2:
            txt.append(f2.read())
    with open(f, 'w') as f3:
        f3.write(''.join(txt))
```

Comment: So your goal is to combine all files called `patch_1.txt`, `patch_2.txt`, etc. into a single file called `patch.txt`?

Comment: do the various files have all different ````"numbers"```` in file name? are there duplicated filenames in the various directories? are the file numbers important for the sequence of reading and processing the files?

Comment: @SitiSchu yes, my goal is exactly what you said

Comment: @Iroth yes there are duplicated files in different directories. The number is not important. I just need to check if the file name starts with "patch_".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should have a global txt variable which would append all file content into it. and finally you write it to one file which is something like this:

```
import os

paths = {}
for root, directories, files in os.walk('.'):
    for f in files:
        if f.startswith('patch_', 0, 5):
            if f not in paths:
                paths[f] = []
            paths[f].append(root)

txt = []
for f, paths in paths.items():
    for p in paths:
        with open(os.path.join(p, f)) as f2:
            txt.append(f2.read())
          
with open(f, 'w') as f3:
    f3.write(''.join(txt))
```